# Shift tabbing in Visual Studio 2019 does not work when selecting an entire line

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, visual-studio, visual-studio-2019

If I highlight an *entire* line of text in Visual Studio 2019, including any leading whitespace, the <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> hotkey does not decrease the level of indentation.

It only works if I select everything *after* the leading whitespace.

This is very frustrating to me, as I often select entire lines using <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>↓</kbd> and <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>↑</kbd>, and would like to be able to quickly change their level of indentation.

Is there any setting I can change, or extension I can add, to make this work in the desired fashion? Every other code editor I've ever used lets <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> work if the whole line is selected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually it will work when really an entire line is selected.
This is mean to select an entire line use one of the following ways:

1. Set cursor to first position in the line and press <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>↓</kbd>
2. Using mouse left button double-click on end of a line.

After selecting an entire line by this way the <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> will  decrease the level of indentation.

***NOTE:**

The <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> doesn't work when only visible part of a line is selected, without the End-Of-Line (EOL) hidden formatting symbol, that usually doesn't displayed in the editor.*

Comment: Oh I see! I didn't realize it until you pointed it out, but instead of just doing Shift + ↓, I was actually doing Shift+↓, then Shift+← - which keeps the entire line selected _except_ that End-Of-Line character.

I think I'd gotten into the habit of that to remove line breaks when copying and pasting text, and it had become so automatic that it didn't consciously register. Doh.

In my previous editor-of-choice, VS Code, having that EOL character didn't matter, but in VS I guess it does. Thanks a ton!

Comment: @ChristianMay: I see. Yes it depends on the implementation of the text editor function. You are welcome!